# @HystricCommand not Configured

Tags: spring-boot, hystrix, spring-cloud-config

I am using `@HystrixCommand` in a `@Component` in a Spring Boot application configured using Spring Cloud Config and the Hystrix command is not picking the configuration.

If I use the Actuator `env` endpoint, I see my Hystrix configuration.

```
"hystrix.command.default.circuitBreaker.enabled": true,
"hystrix.command.default.circuitBreaker.requestVolumeThreshold": 20,
"hystrix.command.default.circuitBreaker.sleepWindowInMilliseconds": 20000,
"hystrix.command.default.execution.isolation.strategy": "THREAD",
"hystrix.command.default.execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds": 10000,
"hystrix.command.default.execution.timeout.enabled": true,
"hystrix.command.default.metrics.rollingStats.numBuckets": 200,
"hystrix.command.default.metrics.rollingStats.timeInMilliseconds": 10000,
```

If I use the `archaius` endpoint I see nothing.

```
{}
```

I can see the configuration using following in my fallback. It confirms I am only getting configuration from the `@HystrixCommand`.

```
HystrixCircuitBreaker circuitBreaker = HystrixCircuitBreaker.Factory.getInstance(commandKey);
HystrixReporter.reportMetric(HystrixCommandMetrics.getInstance(commandKey), text -> logger.debug(text));
```

I can use the `@HystrixCommand` to configure the Hystric command but want dynamic run-time configuration.

Here is a snippet from my `build.gradle`.

```
springBootVersion = '1.5.4.RELEASE'

...

ext {
    springCloudVersion = 'Dalston.SR1'
}

dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-config')
    compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-feign')
    compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-hystrix')
    compile('org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-jms')
```

I keep seeing this comment so it should "just" work:

> External Configuration: a bridge from the Spring Environment to Archaius

Here is the `application.yml` supplied by Spring Cloud Config server.

```
hystrix:
  command:
    default:
      circuitBreaker:
        enabled: true
        requestVolumeThreshold: 20
        sleepWindowInMilliseconds: 20000
      execution:
        isolation:
          strategy: THREAD
          thread:
            timeoutInMilliseconds: 10000
        timeout:
          enabled: true
      metrics:
        rollingStats:
          numBuckets: 200
          timeInMilliseconds: 10000

  threadpool:
    default:
      coreSize: 10
      maximumSize: 10
      maxQueueSize: -1

  metrics:
    polling-interval-ms: 5000
```

Comment: Spring Cloud injects all property sources of spring into Archiaus configuration. But Spring Cloud Archaius endpoint just shows the properties that were defined in Archaius directly after excluding all properties that were injected by Spring Cloud. That's probably why you can't see any properties in Archaius endpoint

Comment: I wouldn't have even looked at the `archiaus` endpoint if I thought my `@HystrixCommand` was being configured properly but when I observe behavior and report on metrics I am very clearly aware that the command is not being configured by Spring Cloud Config.

Comment: Do you mean that you configured same properties via spring cloud config, but it doesn't work ? If so, could you post your setting for spring cloud config that exists in bootstrap.yml ?

Comment: I am using a Spring Cloud Config server so my `bootstrap.yml` points to the server. I included some of the configuration loaded by my config client in my post. I got that using the Actuator `env` endpoint on the client. The one that I have zeroed in on is `"hystrix.command.default.execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds": 10000`. That is a 10 second time out but the actual command is being configured with the default 1 second time out.